# Conservation of momentum or Kinetic Energy. Which one works here?

Tags: energy, momentum, velocity

EDIT:

**Question**

If a block, suspending from a string and with a mass of $0.5kg$ is hit by a pellet weighing $0.001kg$ (the pellet embeds itself in the block), and the centre of mass of the block is raised vertically by $0.5m$, then what is the velocity of the pellet before impact? - Disregard energy losses from friction etc.

**Solving using KE**

GPE of block at $0.5m$, must be $mgh$, which is $0.501kg9.81\frac{m}{s^2}0.5m$, which is $2.457405 J$.

As friction is not considered, we know that the conservation of energy means all of this GPE would have been KE when the block was first hit, and all of this KE would have originally been KE of the pellet before impact.

Therefore, KE of the bullet before impact must be equal to 2.457405 J, meaning rearraning $KE = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$, for $v$ gives, $v = \sqrt{\frac{2*KE}{m}}$, which is $70.1057059019 \frac{m}{s}$.

**Solving using momentum**

As we worked out above, the KE of the block with the pellet embedded, immediately after impact was $2.457405 J$, meaning the KE at impact was 2.457405 and hence the v at impact of the block was the root of (2*2.457405/0.501), which is 3.132. As $p=mv$, this gives us a momentum of 3.132*0.501, which is 1.569 N·s$.

The conservation of momentum means this momentum must have been the same for the pellet immediately before the impact, so solving for $v$, $v=\frac{p}{m}$, so velocity is equal to $\frac{1.569}{0.001}$, which is 1569 m/s.

**Why are these two values so different?**

Please could someone explain why the values are so different, as I was under the impression that the conservation of momentum and conservation of energy always applied, yet they both give a different answer to the same question. Also, which answer is the correct version?

Comment: This problem is usually termed a "ballistic pendulum" (and it is the mechanism long used to measure muzzle velocities for firearms).

Comment: Yes, conservation of momentum always applies and conservation of energy is always true (if you understand conservation laws properly), but kinetic energy is *not* a general conservation principle.  When the pellet is imbeded, that should tell you *conceptually* what the important principles are. Go back and review collision principles.

Answer (score 2):

The conservation of momentum solution is the correct one.

I'd assume "ignore energy losses due to friction" refers only to after the collision. You *can't* avoid energy losses due to friction if the bullet sticks in the block.

You can most easily see that kinetic energy can't possibly be conserved by considering what this collision looks like in the center of mass frame. Namely, in the center of mass frame, the final kinetic energy is zero. Where does that energy go? Generally speaking, it goes to thermal energy or something similar.

This is true in other reference frames as well- when objects collide and stick together, the final kinetic energy is always less than the initial kinetic energy.

Comment: Agree with Chris but your calculations: *"KE=...2.457405 J, and as p=mv, this gives us a momentum of 2.457405*0.501, which is 1.231159905 Ns."*  are weird. Even the units do not conform.

Comment: @npojo, as far as I know, I did my calculations correctly - With regards to units, Ns is equivalent to kg ms^-1.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but it seems like: *LHS=[Joul * kg] = [kg * m / sec]=RHS* ?

Comment: I understand that in reality, KE would never be conserved. However, in theory, surely it could be possible that absolutely no energy is wasted and it is all converted into KE of the block (with pellet embedded). Even in this situation, the equations still don't produce the same result.

Comment: @npojo - Sorry, I missed that. Rushed through and forgot to solve KE for v. It should be correct now, but it still gives a very different answer to using KE and not P. Thank you very much for pointing out my error.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy No. It's not possible. In a collision where the colliding objects stick together, it is impossible for KE to be conserved.

Comment: @Chris - please could you explain why this is, as I can't visualise what would happen to the excess energy that isn't conserved? I see you just edited your comment to say it goes to thermal energy. However, surely the amount of energy converted to thermal energy would depend on the material of the block, and hence this equation should be a different answer for each material?

Comment: @PhysicsGuy I'll add a bit more to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The system is the bullet and the block and during the collision you make the key assumption that there are no horizontal external forces acting on the system
This being the case means that the horizontal momentum of the system is the same before and after the collision.

Now consider what happens to the bullet and the block as the bullet penetrates the block.
There are frictional forces acting which will mean that some of the kinetic energy of the system will be converted into heat.
Work is done permanently breaking the bonds between molecules which make up the block (and the bullet) and this results in the kinetic energy of the system decreasing.
Vibrations are caused by the block passing through the block and this results in sound waves being emitted the energy of which comes from the kinetic energy of the system.

So overall the initial kinetic energy of the bullet is transferred to the kinetic energy of the bullet and the block and some is used in heating the bullet and the block, permanently deforming the block, and producing sound.

This type of collision is called an inelastic collision.
If the kinetic energy is conserved then the collision is called an elastic collision.
You can also have a "collision" where the kinetic energy increases and then it is called a super elastic collision.
An example of such a collision would be one where a chemical explosion occurred.

However whatever the type of collision if there are no external horizontal forces acting then the horizontal momentum of the bullet and the block will remain constant.

After the collision the "no frictional forces acting" means that you can assume that mechanical energy is conserved and the kinetic energy of the bullet and the block after collision is converted into gravitational potential energy as they rise and eventually stop.

Answer (score 0):

Chris gave a good answer.  However, you still seem to be troubled by what happens to the missing energy.

The bullet "wants" to bounce off the block such that after the collision the bullet and block are separating just as fast as they were coming together beforehand.  This is what an elastic collision looks like.  In order to prevent this from happening, the block has to "grab" onto the pellet and bring it to rest relative to the block.  In doing so, a bunch of kinetic energy is transformed into thermal energy: the block and pellet are now warmer.

Comment: I understand that this would be the case in reality. However, I fail to see why this would be a set amount (the difference between the two results) - surely it would depend on the material of the block and pellet as to how much of the kinetic energy would be converted to thermal energy.

Comment: No, the material properties might have an effect on how long it takes the pellet to come to rest, whether it bounces back at all within the block before coming to rest, how far it penetrates into the block, etc.  But there is a certain definite amount of energy that must be dissipated in order to bring the pellet and block to the same velocity and conserve momentum. It is equal to the total kinetic energy of the pellet and block before the collision in the center of mass frame.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand that you cannot avoid dissipating at least some of the energy.

Comment: The takeaway is that when it comes to the kinematics of collisions, conservation of energy is only valid/useful for *elastic* collisions. Conservation of momentum is always ok (but not always useful, as in the case of a ball bouncing off a wall).

Comment: I may be overthinking this, but if we were to assume the dissipated energy is converted into another form, such as electrical energy, which is then used to power a motor to lift the block higher than 0.5m, then once the block is released and reaches the bottom of the pendulum, it will have a higher momentum than the momentum of the pellet before impact. Surely given this is the result of a single incident, the motor cannot be expressed as an external force, yet momentum is still not conserved within the system.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy Said motor *is* a force external to the system, so you don't expect momentum to be conserved. The momentum for a system is always conserved if there are no external forces. If you consider the motor to be part of the system, then the external force is the normal force that the ground provides to hold the motor up.

Comment: @Chris - Thank you for your help. I was simply finding it hard to visualise this, as I was always under the impression that the conservation of energy meant that in any situation, you could "choose" which form of energy you wished to convert the energy into, but this has proven to me that during inelastic collisions, you cannot avoid losing energy to unwanted forms and therefore 100% efficiency is almost impossible, even when conditions are as perfect as possible.